# button is still clickable after call window.alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to prevent multiple submit. To prevent to submit the same value, I called window.alert to stop the process and tell the user the input value is already registered. The problem is the submit seems to be clickable after the alert window opened. Because after clicking the button several times after the alert window opens, and I closed the alert window. the alert window immediately re-opened without any clicks. the submit button seems to clickable after the windo open. how to disable all input right after the alert window open?

I was trying to disable a button by setting the state. However, it didn't work.

```
HTML  
<form onSubmit={(e) => submitHandler(e)}>
        <input
          name="words"
          value={words}
          placeholder="Enter Tag for search"
          onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e)}
        />
        {disable ? (
          <h1>updating</h1>
        ) : (
          <button type="submit" disable={disable}>
            submit
          </button>
        )}
      </form>


const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!words) {
      return null;
    }
    setNewSearchWordsState({ ...newSearchWordsState, disable: true });
    const newList = list.map((item, idx) => {
      if (idx === id) {
        item.searchWords.map((searchWord) => {
          if (searchWord === words) {
            setNewSearchWordsState({ ...newSearchWordsState, words: '' });
            window.alert(`${words} already registered`);
          }
          item.searchWords.push(words.toLowerCase());
        });
      }
      return {
        ...item,
      };
    });
    updateSearchWords(newList);
    setNewSearchWordsState({ words: '', disable: false });
  };
```

Comment: The button element has only `disabled` attribute, doesn't it help if you use that one instead of `disable`?

Comment: @ikarasz thank you for your comment. I tried disabled={disable}. but it does not solve issue.

Comment: Change `setNewSearchWordsState({ words: '', disable: false }); to setNewSearchWordsState({ words: '', disable: true});`

Comment: @Sohail hi. which part of the code are you mentioning? if you mean Initial state, it doesn't make sense. because I need to able the button initially.

Comment: Inside submitHandler function. Second last line in your code.

Comment: @Sohail it doesnt work. because after finishing submit, I need to enable the button again.

Comment: I noticed one thing, your alert is inside map function and the map function body will execute multiple time. Is this causing the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201404/discussion-between-sohail-and-shincat).

Answer (score -1):

You may want try this working sample https://codepen.io/cunlay/pen/BaaROPG

```
// HTML

<form onsubmit="submitHandler()">
    <input id="words" onkeyup="changeHandler()" placeholder="Enter Tag for search" />
    <button type="submit" id="btn" disabled=true>Submit</button>
</form>

//JAVASCRIPT

<script>
function changeHandler(){
  var words = document.getElementById('words'); 
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn'); 
  var text = words.value;

  if(!text){
    btn.disabled = true;
  }else{
    btn.disabled = false;
  }
}

function submitHandler(){
  //Your code here
  alert("submitted");
  return false;
}
</script>
```